# Up Down Buttons of the NumericUpDown Control Won't Hide

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, hide, draw, numericupdown

So I have a numeric up down control in place, and I want to make the up-down (increment and decrement) buttons hidden. So far I have set it up within the value changed event for testing purposes. Basically once the value becomes greater than 3 the buttons are supposed to become hidden. The code looks something like this:

```
    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (numericUpDown1.Value > 3)
        {
            //numericUpDown1.Controls[0].Visible = false;
            numericUpDown1.Controls[0].Hide();
            numericUpDown1.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

It works... Sort of. You see the buttons become disabled, as in I cannot click them any more but they are still clearly visible. It looks something like this:

[image: Ignore the Textbox]

The textbox is just part of another test where basically you take the value of the numericupdown control and subtract it from 10, the answer goes in the textbox.

As you can see I have tried setting the visible property in the past and have even tried to force the entire control to redraw itself, but nothing seems to be working at this point. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why not just disable buttons instead? In the case of disabling, there is no problems related to the improper painting.

Comment: That probably would work, but its not as aesthetically pleasing to me. I would rather them be invisible when they are not available any ways, rather than have the option there but have it unclickable.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification, do you want to hide the up and down controls because somehow you wanted to prevent users from incrementing the value of the NumericUpDown control to a specific value? Because if it's the case, can't you just use the `Maximum` property of the NumericUpDown control to do the job?

And besides, do have a way to unhide the buttons if the value *(in your case)* is not greater than 3 anymore?

**Update #1**

This is a just a workaround to the problem your having. I tried hiding the updown buttons like in your example above but failed to get the results as well, hiding the control only worked before the control was actually drawn.

So what I did was, I added a textbox from the your above example that will receive the value of the numericupdown control, and made the width of the numericupdown small enough just to display the updown buttons. See the picture below

[image]

The blue control is a textbox, the red one is the numericupdown and the green one is another textbox.

```
private void greenTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text.Trim()) <= 0)
    {
        redNumericUpDown.Visible = false;
        redNumericUpDown.Refresh();
    }
    else
    {
        redNumericUpDown.Visible = true;
        redNumericUpDown.Refresh();
    }
}  

private void redNumericUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    blueTextBox.Text = redNumericUpDown.Value.ToString();
    greenTextBox.Text = (10 - redNumericUpDown.Value).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion, but I don't think it will work for what I am trying to do. You see, long term I want the buttons to become invisible when the number within the textbox below the numericupdown control reaches 0. Although I could make the maximum 10, but if I wanted the textbox number to be affected by multiple numericupdowns then one may be 4, another may be 5, and a third could be 1, and since they all add up to ten I would like to at that point make the buttons invisible. As for why I have it set as not greater than 3, that was just for test purposes so that I only had to click 3 times.

Comment: If using other numericupdowns, do they have the same behaviour like the numericupdown from your example above?

Comment: Yes, the up down buttons will have to be hidden when the "Counter" reaches zero as well. My problem is still that I need to find a way to force the correct redraw of the numericupdfown control with the hidden buttons.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @J0e3gan, thanx for the reminder, won't happen again ^_^